# Accessing friendly iframe contents in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe

I've created a [friendly iframe](http://sparecycles.wordpress.com/2012/03/08/inject-content-into-a-new-iframe/) (same domain) and added it to the DOM with JavaScript. It's visible on my page. Inspecting the HTML looks like:

```
<iframe id="test_frame" frameSpacing="0" height="100" src="javascript:window['contents']" width="100" name="test_frame">
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>test_frame</title>
      <base target=_top>
    </head>
    <body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px">
      <p>Hello World</p>
    </body>
  </html>
</iframe>
```

Then I run the following in order to access the markup in the iframe's `<body>`:

```
    alert(window.frames["test_frame"].document.body.innerHTML);
```

**which fails for Internet Explorer 6-10 because `body` is `null`**. The `document` object of the iframe exists, but appears to have no readable properties. Other browsers simply display the string `<p>Hello World</p>`.

But interestingly, the following works in IE 6-10, and all other browsers:

```
    window.setTimeout(function(){
      alert(window.frames["test_frame"].document.body.innerHTML);
    }, 1);
```

To my knowledge `setTimeout` executes the passed function in the global scope. So I tried using [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) but it does *not* work:

```
    (function(){
      alert(window.frames["test_frame"].document.body.innerHTML);
    }).call(window);
```

I have seen similar cases where wrapping code in a setTimeout resolves IE iframe difficulties. **What is the mechanism or logic behind this in IE? Is there a proper workaround?**

*Above tests were run in standards mode, with no other errors than those stated.*

Comment: When are you calling the method? The content may not be already loaded.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the mechanism or logic behind this in IE? Is there a proper workaround?

The mechanism is very simple: wait one milisecond (four; actually), then attempt to access the iFrame.

*Timing is everything. If you call too soon, you will see an empty iFrame.* Even if the `src` is javascript code, you have to let the code run.

---

- If you access the iFrame just after it is encountered in the DOM: most likely it will be empty. It has not been fetched from the Internet yet. *Even if the `src` is `javascript:...`, the iFrame will be empty*.
- If you do it 1 millisecond after the page load, most likely it has not been fetched yet either. However, if it's in the browser cache (normally a page shouldn't be) or it's a data (or javascript, in your case) URL, however, this will likely work (nothing's granted, though). The `document.body` element may already exist at this point - even if it's going to be empty.
- The intended workflow is that you wait for the iFrame `load` event. You can safely attach it just after you create the iFrame or set its `src`. Finding a cross-browser set of events that messages this reliably is a tricky issue, but `load` should work cross-browser.
- If the `load` event fails to be late enough, wait an extra millisecond. This should not be neccessary, but there might be a stupid bug in IE (I don't think there is).
- It you are firing it from the console, this should be successful. Indeed, this has always been the case according to my observation.